# can't build link-os sdk for android demo code

Tags: java, android, sdk, zebra-printers

I'm following the instructions on loading the demo code for the link-os SDK here https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/android/ and it seems like it should be very simple, but upon trying to build it in android studio it tells me

```
Unsupported Gradle. 
The project uses Gradle 2.14.1 which is incompatible with Android Studio 2022.3.

Possible solution:
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 3.0 version and re-import the project
```

when clicking on the upgrade gradle wrapper it'll change all of the dependencies, but then once that's done I get

`Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler`

I've also tried running this in eclipse but it'll immediately give me the second error. Does anyone know the proper way to load all of this and set it up?

Comment: The project is too old to be used with Android Studio. Just use `./gradlew` on command-line to build, e.g. `./gradlew assemblerelease`. But often such old unmaintained projects are not worth the effort up migrate it to a recent version as such projects target an outdated Android version there is a high chance that it will not work even if you manage to compile it.

Comment: Sadly there's no recent project, this is a first party SDK and the only one that does what I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the [ZSDK_DevDemos_Combined](https://github.com/Zebra/LinkOS-Android-Samples/tree/ZSDK_DevDemos_Combined), which was updated for Gradle v4.2.2 for Android Studio last year.

After open the [ZSDK_DevDemos_Combined](https://github.com/Zebra/LinkOS-Android-Samples/tree/ZSDK_DevDemos_Combined) in Android Studio, click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button first before start building the project.

Comment: I think this worked. I haven't tested the build to see if there's any issues with it, but it finished the build without any error messages after automatically updating the wrapper.